# Error during prepare to release phase using Maven Relelase Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'am new in Maven and trying to perform release using maven-release-plugin.
After running mvn release:prepare i receive following info in console:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Feeder 1.0.3-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) @
>   Feeder --- [INFO] Resuming release from phase 'run-preparation-goals'
>   [INFO] Executing goals 'clean install'... [WARNING] Error injecting:
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Options;  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)    at
>   com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:661)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:165)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:609)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:565)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:551)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:865)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1054)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
>     at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
>     at java.util.AbstractMap.get(AbstractMap.java:187)  at
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute(AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.phase.RunPrepareGoalsPhase.execute(RunPrepareGoalsPhase.java:44)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.shared.release.DefaultReleaseManager.prepare(DefaultReleaseManager.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.prepareRelease(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:286)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.commons.cli.Options    at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
>     ... 67 more [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 1.578 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2015-04-30T12:17:24+03:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/155M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare
>   (default-cli) on project Feeder: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare failed: A
>   required class was missing while executing
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare:
>   Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Options; [ERROR]
>   ----------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2 [ERROR]
>   strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
>   [ERROR] urls[0] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.5.2/maven-release-plugin-2.5.2.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[1] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/release/maven-release-manager/2.5.2/maven-release-manager-2.5.2.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[2] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/release/maven-release-api/2.5.2/maven-release-api-2.5.2.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[3] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[4] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
>   [ERROR] urls[5] =
>   file:/C:/Users/Maya/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-6/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-6.jar
>   [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1 [ERROR] import: Entry[import 
>   from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]] [ERROR]  [ERROR]
>   -----------------------------------------------------: org.apache.commons.cli.Options [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To
>   see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
>   switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug
>   logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and
>   possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help
>   1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException

My POM file look like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mayacomp</groupId>
  <artifactId>feeder</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


  <scm>
   <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn01/svn/DEV/Maya/Code/feeder/tag/feeder-1.0.3</developerConnection>
   <url>scm:svn:http://svn01/svn/DEV/Maya/Code/feeder/tag/feeder-1.0.3</url>
 </scm>

  <properties>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>


 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shared-utils</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archiver</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-common-artifact-filters</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>${jdk.version}</source>
            <target>${jdk.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.mayacomp.feeder.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>



    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.mayacomp.feeder.App</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.2</version>
        <configuration>
                    <tagBase>http://svn01/svn/DEV/Maya/Code/feeder/tag</tagBase>
                    <branchBase>http://svn01/svn/DEV/Maya/Code/feeder/branches</branchBase>
                    <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                   <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
          </configuration>
     </plugin>


    </plugins>
  </build>


<distributionManagement>
 <repository>
    <id>com-mayacomp-retail-release</id>
    <url>http://192.168.0.17::8080/nexus-webapp-2.11.0-02/content/repositories/com-mayacomp-retail-release</url>
  </repository>
   <snapshotRepository>
    <id>com-mayacomp-retail-snapshot</id>
    <url>http://192.168.0.17::8080/nexus-webapp-2.11.0-02/content/repositories/com-mayacomp-retail-snapshot</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
 </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

### UPDATE 1:

Fixed scm element in pom:

```
<scm> <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn01/svn/DEV/Maya/Code/Feeder/trunk</developerConnection>
<url>scm:svn:http://svn01/svn/DEV/Maya/Code/Feeder/trunk</url>
</scm>
```

Comment: Which maven version do you use? Are you trying to do it on command line or from within Eclipse?

Comment: I am using apache-maven-3.2.3 and I'am doing it from eclipse.

Comment: Look like the core of problem is here: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare: Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Options;

Comment: You have to call release:prepare from Command line and **NOT** from within Eclipse.

Comment: Looks very strange but when i restart Eclipse and Windows and call mvn clean release:clean release:prepare  everything goes fine!!!  khmarbaise, thank you.

Comment: Don't do releases within Eclipse. Only on command line. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't define things like `maven-assembly-plugin`, `maven-shared-utils`, `maven-common-artifact-filters`, `maven-release-plugin` as dependencies. These are plugins which you don't need to define as dependencies. They are not related to your production code in any way. Furthermore you don't need to defined `tagBase`, `branchBase` and `preparationGoals` and `goal` in the maven-release-plugin configuration  cause it looks like you have a default folder layout in the svn repository.

The most important part is that you need to change the scm entries to represent the trunk and **NOT** a tag, which is the default if you are working on a SNAPSHOT like you do.

Comment: The result is the same: [INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:prepare (default-cli) @ Feeder ---
[INFO] Resuming release from phase 'run-preparation-goals'
[INFO] Executing preparation goals - since this is simulation mode it is running against the original project, not the rewritten ones
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean verify'...
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/commons/cli/Options;